# How to query within a specific subtitle for the word "Eat" in AWS Elastic Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an index called Videos.
Each video has subtitles.
I want to query for the word "eat" within subtitle id 4851.

How can I do this?

Comment: please support your questions with schema mappings.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I think you should either change the mapping of your object to have documents with small parts of subtitle, either play with higlights :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id": 4851
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "subtitle": "eat"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "subtitle": {}
    },
    "pre_tags": "",
    "post_tags": ""
  }
}
```